# Update choices in dynamically generated selectizeInput(s) given selected value in previous selectizeInput(s)

Tags: r, shiny

I am dynamically generating a number of selectizeInputs based on a reactive value, and attempting to restrict the choices in dropdown2, by removing the selected value of dropdown1 from available choices in dropdown2. The solution should extend for all dynamically generated n dropdowns i.e. for dropdown3, the available choices should be all `LETTERS` except `A` and `B` (assuming selection in dropdown1 is `A` and selection in dropdown2 is `B`). If the user changes selection in dropdown1 to `Z` then `A` should become available in choices for dropdown3.

I'm having some issues trying to do this, I'm attempting to do this in renderUI by first creating reactive values to store the inputs then using `setdiff` to restrict choices. I know  `updateSelectizeInput()` can update choices but this could get quite verbose as the number of dropdowns increase. Thank you in advance for the help and suggestions.

See reprex:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "ndropdowns", label = "Number of dropdowns", value = 1),
  uiOutput("dropdowns")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$dropdowns <- renderUI({
    uiDropdowns <- vector(mode = "list", length = input$ndropdowns)
    for(i in seq_along(uiDropdowns) ){
     uiDropdowns[[i]] <- tagList(
        selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("dropdown", i), label =  paste0("dropdown", i), choices = setdiff(LETTERS,  selectedCols$values))
      )
    }
    uiDropdowns
  })
  
  selectedCols <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
  
  observe({
    isolate({
    selectedCols$values <- c(input$dropdown1, input$dropdown2, input$dropdown3)
    })
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be one way to approach this, based on what you have already. For each of your inputs, use `updateSelectizeInput` in a loop and remove selected elements with each input. This includes setting `selected` so that the inputs don't change value when another input changes (unless the value is no longer possible from more proximal inputs).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "ndropdowns", label = "Number of dropdowns", value = 1),
  uiOutput("dropdowns")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$dropdowns <- renderUI({
    uiDropdowns <- vector(mode = "list", length = input$ndropdowns)
    for(i in seq_along(uiDropdowns) ){
      uiDropdowns[[i]] <- tagList(
        selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("dropdown", i), label =  paste0("dropdown", i), choices = LETTERS)
      )
    }
    uiDropdowns
  })
  
  observe({
    current_selections <- sapply(1:input$ndropdowns, function(i) input[[paste0("dropdown", i)]])
    choice_set <- c()
    uiDropdowns <- vector(mode = "list", length = input$ndropdowns)
    for(i in seq_along(uiDropdowns) ){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("dropdown", i), choices = setdiff(LETTERS, choice_set), selected = current_selections[i])
      choice_set <- c(choice_set, input[[paste0("dropdown", i)]])
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```